# Why do I get a segmentation fault when calling a CUDA kernel directly from a shared library?

Tags: cuda, cmake

The way I tried it (see question title) it compiled, but I get a segmentation fault. So is it me, CMake or CUDA which doesn't support direct kernel calls from a shared library? The solution doesn't have to be with CMake

Further details:

---

I have the following file structure:

testKernel.hpp

```
__global__ void kernelTest( float x );
void callKernel( float x );
```

testKernel.cu

```
#include "testKernel.hpp"

__global__ void kernelTest( float x ) {}
void callKernel( float x ) { kernelTest<<<1,1>>>( x ); }
```

useKernel.cu

```
#include <cstdio>
#include "testKernel.hpp"

int main( void )
{
    kernelTest<<<1,1>>>( 3.0f );
    //callKernel( 3.0f );
    printf("OK\n");
    return 0;
}
```

CMakeLists.txt

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.3.1)
project(testKernelCall)
find_package(CUDA REQUIRED)

cuda_add_library( ${PROJECT_NAME} SHARED testKernel.cu testKernel.hpp )
target_link_libraries( ${PROJECT_NAME} ${CUDA_LIBRARIES} )

cuda_add_executable("useKernel" useKernel.cu)
target_link_libraries("useKernel" ${PROJECT_NAME})
```

Compiling and running this with:

```
cmake .; make && ./useKernel
```

results in a segmentation fault. The backtrace with gdb is:

```
Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
0x00007ffff75726bd in cudart::configData::addArgument(void const*, unsigned long, unsigned long) ()
   from ./libtestKernelCall.so
(gdb) bt
#0  0x00007ffff75726bd in cudart::configData::addArgument(void const*, unsigned long, unsigned long) ()
   from ./libtestKernelCall.so
#1  0x00007ffff7562eb7 in cudart::cudaApiSetupArgument(void const*, unsigned long, unsigned long) ()
   from ./libtestKernelCall.so
#2  0x00007ffff7591ca2 in cudaSetupArgument ()
   from ./libtestKernelCall.so
#3  0x00007ffff7556125 in __device_stub__Z10kernelTestf (__par0=3)
    at /tmp/tmpxft_00003900_00000000-4_testKernel.cudafe1.stub.c:7
#4  0x00007ffff755616c in kernelTest (__cuda_0=3) at ./testKernel.cu:2
#5  0x000000000040280e in main () at ./useKernel.cu:6
```

Tested with (which means the segfault appears in those setups):

- Setup 1

  - cmake 3.4.1
  - CUDA 7.0.27
  - g++ 4.9.2
  - Debian
- Setup 2

  - cmake 3.3.1
  - CUDA 6.5.14
  - g++ 4.7.1

There are two ways to solve this error:

- change `SHARED` to `STATIC` in CMakeList.txt
- use the wrapper function `callKernel` instead of calling the kernel directly

I don't really know how to build a CUDA shared library without CMake. I know how to build a CUDA static library, but that case seems to work with CMake, so I didn't test it without CMake.

Here are the relevant CMake commands I got with `make VERBOSE=1`. I changed absolute paths to relative paths, where possible, but I wasn't sure about all these library paths. Putting these commands in a file and sourcing that file compiles the shared library and the program correctly and "correctly" leads to the segmentation fault. I also added `command` because for me `nvcc` is aliased with the `-ccbin`` option.

make.sh

```
command nvcc "./testKernel.cu" -c -o "./testKernel.cu.o" -ccbin /usr/bin/cc -m64 -DtestKernelCall_EXPORTS -Xcompiler ,\"-fPIC\",\"-g\" -DNVCC -I/opt/cuda-7.0/include -I/opt/cuda-7.0/include
/usr/bin/c++  -fPIC   -shared -Wl,-soname,libtestKernelCall.so -o libtestKernelCall.so ./testKernel.cu.o /opt/cuda-7.0/lib64/libcudart_static.a -lpthread /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/librt.so /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdl.so /opt/cuda-7.0/lib64/libcudart_static.a -lpthread /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/librt.so /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdl.so
command nvcc "./useKernel.cu" -c -o "./useKernel.cu.o" -ccbin /usr/bin/cc -m64 -Xcompiler ,\"-g\" -DNVCC -I/opt/cuda-7.0/include -I/opt/cuda-7.0/include
/usr/bin/c++ ./useKernel.cu.o  -o useKernel -rdynamic /opt/cuda-7.0/lib64/libcudart_static.a -lpthread /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/librt.so /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdl.so libtestKernelCall.so /opt/cuda-7.0/lib64/libcudart_static.a -lpthread /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/librt.so /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdl.so -Wl,-rpath,"."
```

Comment: Obviously it is possible. That is how libraries like CUBLAS and CUFfT work

Comment: @talonmies: do they? cuFFT at least I used and the calls like cufftC2CExec aren't direct kernel calls, they are wrappers inside the shared library which then call the kernel.

Comment: How is CMake involved in your segfault? Most probably unrelated.

Comment: I was able to reproduce this, even without cmake (Debian Jessie, g++ 4.9.2-10, cuda V7.0.27), so at least it's not just you...

Comment: Can you provide the the relevant compiler calls from running `make VERBOSE=1`

Comment: @ebarr: I added the cmake output to the question.

Comment: I can show you how to get this to work without using CMake.  In a nutshell,  do your `nvcc` compile steps with `-cudart shared`.  I can provide an answer if that is what you're looking for.    I'm not a CMake expert, however.

Comment: @RobertCrovella Did you test this? Because the nutshell version doesn't work for me. I added `-cudart shared` in `make.sh` before the two `-c` options. But maybe I forgot to change something else and if you'd explain that in more detail in your answer, I would accept it. Although an answer also including how to do it in CMake would be even better, because this is from a larger project. If it is only about a missing argument `set(CUDA_NVCC_FLAGS -cudart shared)` should make it work with CMake, if it is more, maybe someone else can convert your solution to CMake.

Comment: I've added an answer explaining this, but the `-cudart shared` is basically a *link* directive, not a compile directive (sorry I was unclear in my previous comment.)  So the fix is to have CMake link against `libcudart.so` not `libcudart_static.a`.  If you were compiling *and linking* with `nvcc`, then `-cudart shared` would be correct.  Since you are linking with the host compiler, you need to point it at the shared library version of cudart, i.e. `libcudart.so`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code compiles and runs correctly for me using ordinary `nvcc` commands (not CMake) if I add the `-cudart shared` switch to *each* nvcc command.   Here's a fully-worked sequence:

```
$ cat testKernel.hpp
__global__ void kernelTest( float x );
void callKernel( float x );
$ cat testKernel.cu
#include "testKernel.hpp"

__global__ void kernelTest( float x ) {}
void callKernel( float x ) { kernelTest<<<1,1>>>( x ); }
$ cat useKernel.cu
#include <cstdio>
#include "testKernel.hpp"

int main( void )
{
    kernelTest<<<1,1>>>( 3.0f );
    //callKernel( 3.0f );
    cudaDeviceSynchronize();
    printf("OK\n");
    return 0;
}
$ nvcc -shared -cudart shared -o test.so -Xcompiler -fPIC testKernel.cu
$ nvcc -cudart shared -o test test.so useKernel.cu
$ cuda-memcheck ./test
========= CUDA-MEMCHECK
OK
========= ERROR SUMMARY: 0 errors
$
```

If I omit `-cudart shared` on *either* of the above `nvcc` commands, then the compile will still proceed, but on execution I will witness the aforementioned seg fault.  Tested with CUDA 7.5 on Fedora 20.

Regarding your CMake setup, it's necessary to *link* against the shared cudart, according to my testing.  Therefore it's insufficient to add `-cudart shared` to the `-c` commands (which are compile commands.  Sorry if I was unclear.  My "compile" commands above are doing *both* compiling *and* linking, at each step.)

When linking with `nvcc`, the correct switch is `-cudart shared`.  However, your `make.sh` indicates final link is being done by the host c++ compiler:

```
command nvcc "./testKernel.cu" -c -o "./testKernel.cu.o" -ccbin /usr/bin/cc -m64 -DtestKernelCall_EXPORTS -Xcompiler ,\"-fPIC\",\"-g\" -DNVCC -I/opt/cuda-7.0/include -I/opt/cuda-7.0/include
/usr/bin/c++  -fPIC   -shared -Wl,-soname,libtestKernelCall.so -o libtestKernelCall.so ./testKernel.cu.o /opt/cuda-7.0/lib64/libcudart_static.a -lpthread /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/librt.so /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdl.so /opt/cuda-7.0/lib64/libcudart_static.a -lpthread /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/librt.so /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdl.so
command nvcc "./useKernel.cu" -c -o "./useKernel.cu.o" -ccbin /usr/bin/cc -m64 -Xcompiler ,\"-g\" -DNVCC -I/opt/cuda-7.0/include -I/opt/cuda-7.0/include
/usr/bin/c++ ./useKernel.cu.o  -o useKernel -rdynamic /opt/cuda-7.0/lib64/libcudart_static.a -lpthread /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/librt.so /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdl.so libtestKernelCall.so /opt/cuda-7.0/lib64/libcudart_static.a -lpthread /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/librt.so /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdl.so -Wl,-rpath,"."
```

In that case, you don't want to link against:

```
/opt/cuda-7.0/lib64/libcudart_static.a
```

but instead against `libcudart.so`:

```
/opt/cuda-7.0/lib64/libcudart.so
```

If you were editing your `make.sh` directly, you would want to make that change in *both* of the `/usr/bin/c++` command lines you have shown.  For example, if I were to modify my compile sequence already presented to reflect your usage of the host c++ compiler to do the linking, it would look like this:

```
$ nvcc -c -Xcompiler -fPIC testKernel.cu                     
$ g++ -fPIC -shared -o test.so -L/usr/local/cuda/lib64 -lcudart testKernel.o
$ nvcc -c useKernel.cu
$ g++ -o test -L/usr/local/cuda/lib64 -lcudart test.so useKernel.o
$ cuda-memcheck ./test
========= CUDA-MEMCHECK
OK
========= ERROR SUMMARY: 0 errors
$
```

Comment: Thanks for your time. I needed to append `'-Xlinker -rpath,"."'` to the `nvcc -cudart shared -o test test.so useKernel.cu` call. Your detailed description got me thinking that I maybe should have used `cuda_compile` instead of `target_link_libraries`, but that also doesn't work. Like you said the `make.sh` works after a simple `sed 's/_static.a/.so/g' -i make.sh`. Knowing that adding `set(CUDA_LIBRARIES "${CUDA_TOOLKIT_ROOT_DIR}/lib64/libcudart.so")` after findPackage does the trick, but it looks dirty. `CUDA_USE_STATIC_CUDA_RUNTIME` seems to be ignored, but I'm not sure where how to set it.

Answer (score 1):

put `set(CUDA_USE_STATIC_CUDA_RUNTIME OFF)` before `find_package(CUDA REQUIRED)` will do the job equivalent to `set(CUDA_LIBRARIES "${CUDA_TOOLKIT_ROOT_DIR}/lib64/libcudart.so")`

Answer (score 1):

This is an extension to [Robert Crovella's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35103383/3584162).
I use the following `CMakeLists.txt` and it works well.

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.8)

project(cmake_and_cuda LANGUAGES CXX CUDA)

add_library(my_cu SHARED testKernel.cu testKernel.h)
target_link_libraries(my_cu PRIVATE cudart) #MUST!!
set(CMAKE_CUDA_FLAGS "-shared -cudart shared -Xcompiler -fPIC"
CACHE STRING "Use libcudart.dylib" FORCE)
set(CMAKE_MACOSX_RPATH FALSE)

add_executable(app useKernel.cu)
target_link_libraries(app PRIVATE cudart) #MUST!!
target_link_libraries(app PRIVATE my_cu)
```

I'm using `CMake 3.10` and my OS is `OS X EI Capitan 10.11.6`.
For me, if I don't set `CMAKE_MACOSX_RPATH` to `FALSE`, I will get a `Library not loaded` error. Maybe it is not necessary for you.

Note that since `CMake 3.8`, the `FindCUDA` is superseded, so setting `CUDA_USE_STATIC_CUDA_RUNTIME` affects nothing.
You can check [this post](https://gitlab.kitware.com/cmake/cmake/issues/17150) and [this document](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.10/module/FindCUDA.html?highlight=findcuda) for details.
In addition, [this post](https://devblogs.nvidia.com/building-cuda-applications-cmake/) provides a good example about how to deal with `CUDA` after `CMake 3.8`.